# UITextview resize according to the content

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am developing an app which has a `UITextview` which displays contents after getting it from the DB. The data is propertly fetched from the DB but the height of the `UITextview` is not changing. I tried all the below options

```
//Option1
CGRect frame = messageOne.frame;
frame.size.height = messageOne.textContainer.size.height;
messageOne.frame = frame;


//Option2
CGRect frame = messageOne.frame;
frame.size.height = [messageOne sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(messageOne.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)].height;
messageOne.frame = frame;

//option3
CGFloat fixedWidth = messageOne.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [messageOne sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
CGRect newFrame = messageOne.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
messageOne.frame = newFrame;
[messageOne sizeToFit];
[messageOne layoutIfNeeded];
messageOne.editable = NO;
```

Here messageOne is the `UITextview`. I am placing all this code in the `viewDidLoad`.

The iOS version I am using is 7.

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use contentSize:

```
CGRect frame = messageOne.frame;
frame.size.height = messageOne.contentSize.height;
messageOne.frame = frame;
```

Note that this should be called after you've added your content to the textView.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried this snippet after adding the content in the textview. I executed the code messageOne=textfromDB. Still, I am not able to see the expanded UITextview. Is there any setting change has to be done in XCode?